# Using setCookie from CookieConsent by Insites

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using CookieConsent plugin by Insites and want to use the  "setCookie" function inside "onStatusChange" method to create additional(other) cookies.

```
onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore){
var type = this.options.type;
  var didConsent = this.hasConsented();

  if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
     // enable cookies


  }

}
```

The issues is that I get "Cannot read property 'setCookie' of undefined". Any help will be appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with the relevant JS files and HTML

Comment: Here is my script

Answer (score 0):

This is the plugin where I use:
[link]https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/javascript-api/

and here is my script:

```
<script>

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var p;
window.cookieconsent.initialise({

  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "rgba(255,150,33,0.9)",
      "text": "black"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "transparent",
      "border": "white",
      "text": "black"
    }
  },
  "type": "opt-in",
  "content": {
  message:'The message',
  dismiss:'dismiss',
  allow:'allow',
  link:'Read more', 
  href:'http://example.com',

  },
  revokable:true,
  onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
  var type = this.options.type;
  var didConsent = this.hasConsented();

  if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {

    setCookie('xxx','allow',365,'/','');    

  }
  },
  cookie: {
    name: 'wwwZalarisCC'    
  },
 onRevokeChoice: function(){


 }
}, function (popup) {

    p = popup;
    var output = '';
    for (var property in p) {
  output += property + ': ' + p[property]+'; ';
}

  });
 document.getElementById('btn-revokeChoice').onclick = function (e) {

    p.revokeChoice();

  };
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your `setCookie` function declared?

Comment: SO is a site of questions and answers. Please edit your question with the script and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

in order to create additional/other cookies in your `onStatusChange` function try something like this:

```
onStatusChange: function(status, chosenBefore) {
    var type = this.options.type;
    var didConsent = this.hasConsented();

    if (type === 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
        document.cookie = 'cookie-name=cookie-value; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
    }
}
```

Here you find a longer discussion with several implementation examples:

https://github.com/insites/cookieconsent/issues/205

Hope this helps you!