# Opt in using CookieConsent by Insites

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm having trouble getting this opt in working. I would like to check to see if the user opts-in and then load scripts via GTM but right now I'm just alerting either allow cookies or no cookies but no matter which link I choose I get the alert allow cookies. I am using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456878/using-setcookie-from-cookieconsent-by-insites) as a starting point.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var p;
  window.cookieconsent.initialise({
    "palette": {
      "popup": {
        "background": "rgba(255,255,255,0.9)",
        "text": "black"
      },
      "button": {
        "background": "transparent",
        "border": "white",
        "text": "black"
      }
    },
    "type": "opt-in",
    "content": {
      message: 'The message',
      dismiss: 'dismiss',
      allow: 'allow',
      link: 'Read more',
      href: 'http://example.com',

    },
    revokable: true,
    onStatusChange: function (status, chosenBefore) {
      var type = this.options.type;
      var didConsent = this.hasConsented();
      if (type == 'opt-in' && didConsent) {
        alert('allow cookies');
      } else {
        alert('no cookies');
      }
    },
    onRevokeChoice: function () {
    }
  }, function (popup) {

    p = popup;
    var output = '';
    for (var property in p) {
      output += property + ': ' + p[property] + '; ';
    }
  });
  document.getElementsByClassName("cc-dismiss").onclick = function (e) {
    p.revokeChoice();
  };
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should probably use the "status" value.

```
onStatusChange: function (status, chosenBefore) {
  if (status === "allow") {
    alert('allow cookies');
  } else if (status === "deny"){
    alert('no cookies');
  }else{
    alert("Unhandled state. Denying use of cookies.");
  }
},
```